# What is included in the Javascript code generated by the Dart compiler?

Tags: javascript, dart

When compiling Dart code to Javascript (`dart compile js`) it generates an absolutely massive chunk of JS, 50+ KiB, even for trivial code examples. Can someone please provide more information what exactly does this do? I assume this is some kind of runtime/interpreter, which is confusing to me because I understood that Dart is compiled to native JS, not interpreted in the browser...

Comment: https://dart.dev/faq#q-why-is-the-code-for-hello-world-so-big-compared-to-the-original-dart-code-after-compilation-to-javascript